# HDF5 for data exchange between python and R

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, hdf5

I'm working on a project which needs to save and load multiple:

- Scalars/Matrices/Arrays
- Tables (i.e. Matrices with column and row annotation)

Now I'd like to store all my data in a single file (or transparent data storage), but I'm not sure how to store tables correctly.
How should I save the table's axis labels, in a way keeping the data programming language - independent?

- Pandas or PyTables can access HDF5 files, but they do not allow to store plain NumPy arrays I think. 
  Also, I'm not sure if it is easy to load such special tables into R.
- xarray uses NetCDF format which is based on HDF5, but how can I store multiple Tables + Arrays in one NetCDF file? 
  What about the interoperability with R?
- Simplest option: Just put axes into a separate dataset called [ds name]_axis[n]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is broad, but I will try and dispel some myths to get your started. I only have experience with Python, so my examples will only relate to using HDF5 with Python.

> Pandas or PyTables can access HDF5 files, but they do not allow to
>   store plain NumPy arrays I think.

You are correct in that PyTables doesn't let you save a plain NumPy array without any additional overhead. But you don't *need* to use PyTables. [`h5py`](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/) offers a NumPy-like interface to storing and accessing arrays in / from HDF5 files.

**Store a NumPy array**

```
import h5py, numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, (1000, 1000))

f = h5py.File('file.h5', 'w', libver='latest')  # use 'latest' for performance

dset = f.create_dataset('array', shape=(1000, 1000), data=arr, chunks=(100, 100)
                        compression='gzip', compression_opts=9)
```

There are compression and chunking options which you can explore further to optimise read/write performance and compression ratios, according to your requirements. Note, however, that `gzip` is one of the few compression filters which ship with all HDF5 installations.

**Store axis labels as attributes**

Attributes are similar to datasets and allow you to store a wide range of data, including scalars or arrays.

```
dset.attrs['Description'] = 'Some text snippet'
dset.attrs['X-Labels'] = np.arange(1000)
dset.attrs['Y-Labels'] = np.arange(1000)
```

Internally, data is not stored as NumPy arrays, but in data-type sensitive contiguous memory blocks according to the HDF5 specification. As such, you will be able to read these files from any HDF5 API.

It is worth noting that there are specific requirements to ensure strings are transportable, see [Strings in HDF5](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/strings.html) from the `h5py` docs for more details.